# Fourier transform of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}$

Tags: analysis, fourier-transform

I'm trying to find the fourier transform of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}$ with the fourier transform given as $F(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx$.

I guess I have to find some other representation for $f$ in order to be able  to calculate this but I have no clue where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, yoh can write $x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34$ and express the thing in terms of the Fourier transform of $\frac1{1+x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

You might use G. Sassatelli good hint, and compute the easier calculation then.

Your result will be:

$$\frac{\sqrt[6]{-1} \sqrt{2 \pi } e^{-(-1)^{5/6} n} \left(\theta (-n)+e^{-\sqrt{3} n} \theta (n)\right)}{1+\sqrt[3]{-1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the contour $\gamma=[-R,R]\cup Re^{-i[0,\pi]}$, as $R\to\infty$, which circles the singularity at $x=-\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2$ clockwise,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-inx}}{1+x+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\gamma\frac{e^{-inx}}{\left(x-\left(-\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\right)\left(x-\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\underbrace{\ \ (-2\pi i)\ \ \vphantom{\frac1{\sqrt3}}}_\text{clockwise}\underbrace{\frac{e^{-in\left(-\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)}}{-i\sqrt3}}_\text{residue}\\[6pt]
&=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}3}\,e^{-n\sqrt3/2}e^{in/2}
\end{align}
$$